# Document Library: force column entries in specific folders only

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column, modern-experience, metadata

I want to create a document folder within a existing document library. My goal is to add additional metadata via SharePoint columns (year, product type, etc.) to the document which have to be filled at upload.

I know that I can set specific columns as a "must-fill" but this affects the whole library.

Can I set these default columns in a specific subfolder only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using SharePoint default capabilities.

Any change (setting column as "Required" or setting default value of column value) to column settings will affect whole library & not just single folder/sub-folder.

Comment: So the only option is to create a second library on the SharePoint with these default columns and link it for example in Teams?

Comment: Yes, that approach works I guess.